# Is it safe to expose these particular Firebase derived services?

Tags: android

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43927149/how-to-address-android-lint-complaint-about-exported-firebase-messaging-service) was found on SO. The answer there does not satisfactorily answer the question and since it is a security one and one that warrants a good technical explanation, I am reposting it here. Please let me know if this is not appropriate.

---

Following the [Google developer instructions on implementing Firebase in my app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client), I notice that android lint complains.

The idea is that we have to implement two services which inherit from Firebase services:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService { ... }

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService { ... }
```

and then register those services in the manifest. But, it's not quite perfect. In particular, these two recommended AndroidManifest.xml service entries do not contain any special permissions:

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and so the linter says:

> Exported services (services which either set exported=true or contain an intent-filter and do not specify exported=false) should define a permission that an entity must have in order to launch the service or bind to it. Without this, any application can use this service.

Should I just add this attribute to each service tag and be done with it

```
tools:ignore="ExportedService"
```

or is there a better approach in this situation? I mean, is it safe to expose these particular Firebase derived services like this?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the current FirebaseMessagingService class and not the depricated FirebaseInstanceIdService you can set the

```
android:exported="false"
```

as in given in this official document example [FirebaseMessagingService](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService)

```
<service
 android:name=".YourFirebaseMessagingService"
 android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

and if you're using the old FirebaseInstanceIdService class you don't have to worry about the permission or exported tag because it's stated in the document [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService) Firebase will take care of the security of the service and the intent.

```
<!-- FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
  no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true"             -->
```

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem !

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
 tools:ignore="ExportedService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
 tools:ignore="ExportedService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

**android:exported**

> This element sets whether the activity can be launched by components
>   of other applications — "true" if it can be, and "false" if not. If
>   "false", the activity can be launched only by components of the same
>   application or applications with the same user ID. If you are using
>   intent filters, you should not set this element "false". If you do so,
>   and an app tries to call the activity, system throws an
>   ActivityNotFoundException. Instead, you should prevent other apps from
>   calling the activity by not setting intent filters for it.
>
> If you do not have intent filters, the default value for this element
>   is "false". If you set the element "true", the activity is accessible
>   to any app that knows its exact class name, but does not resolve when
>   the system tries to match an implicit intent.
>
> This attribute is not the only way to limit an activity's exposure to
>   other applications. You can also use a permission to limit the
>   external entities that can invoke the activity (see the permission
>   attribute).